# Почему если я выполняю команду build у меня не создаётся сервер?

Tags: reactjs, сервер, webpack, devops

Есть две команды

```
   "dev": "webpack serve --hot --mode development --config ./configs/webpack.config.ts",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --config ./configs/webpack.config.ts",
```

При запуске в dev у меня создаётся сервер.
При запуске build у меня создаётся билд.

Почему при запуске билд не создаётся сервер локалхост? если указано всегда создавать? если я буду делать билд на настоящем сервере поведение будет такое же?

```
module.exports = (env: Server, argv: Imodul): Iwebpack => {

  let { mode } = argv;

  const isProduction: boolean = mode === 'production';
  const isDevelopment: boolean = mode === 'development';

  return {
    entry: {
      [MAIN]: ['./src/index.js'], 
    },

   
    devServer: {
      port: 3000,
      historyApiFallback: true, 
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: build создает сборку(js - бандл), которую вы уже переносите на ваш сервер и оттуда запускаете. Если это у вас клиентская часть, то просто копируете нужные файлы для выдачи клиенту по хттп. Если это серверная часть, копируете и перезапускаете процесс.

Comment: Вам нужен модуль `webpack-dev-server` а команду измените на `webpack serve` https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#usage-via-cli

Comment: так поняла сервер не запускается так как у меня нет команды webpack serve при запуске билда